# Is correct have a table in a 1 to 1 relationship with a FK that is also a PK?

Tags: sql, database-design, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have one table called Player

- PlayerID (PK)
- More columns

I want to create another table that has a **1 to 1** relationship to Player named PlayerExtraInfo to contain some columns. So I have several options:

1. Instead of creating a new table, add PlayerExtraInfo columns to Player table
2. Create PlayerExtraInfo table and have a FK in Player table.

   **Player** table

   - PlayerID (PK)
   - More columns
   - PlayerExtraInfoID (FK)

   **PlayerExtraInfo** table

   - PlayerExtraInfo (PK)
   - More columns
3. The opposite: PlayerExtraInfo contains a FK to Player table. To get sure that relationship remains 1 to 1 I add a unique constrain.

   **Player** table

   - PlayerID (PK)
   - More columns

   **PlayerExtraInfo** table

   - PlayerExtraInfo (PK)
   - More columns
   - PlayerID (FK,  Unique)
4. Similar to option 3 but mixing PK and FK in one. In this case my foreign key becomes also the primary key:

   **Player** table

   - PlayerID (PK)
   - More columns

   **PlayerExtraInfo** table

   - PlayerID (PK, FK)
   - More columns

I know that options 1, 2 are correct, but due to performance problems I am option for option 3 or 4. And thinking about these 3 and 4 options some doubts about option 4 assault me:
So my questions are:

- **Are options 3 and 4 correct?**
- **Does option 4 break any normal form?**
- **Is there another option I didn't think about?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When extending one table with another one it is absolutely fine (and recommended as well) to use the primary key as the foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

While options 2,3,4 are correct, I would think that option 1 is the one that will give the best performance. Even when using using clustered indexes, an extra join is an extra join. Also a foreign key will degrade performance in respect to the targeted table (I admit that a large number of foreign keys will degrade it, and not one single).

Except the case where the extended table will have but a fraction of the main table's records, or the case where you would like the 2 tables on different partitions, I cannot think of a reason to have that table split into peaces.

Comment: While this is true, it often is premature optimization. And on the other hand, option 4 can be the faster solution if the data in table 2 isn't always required.

Comment: Not really an optimization, is the a starting point for me whenever I expand a table. Also, the only time when option 4 can be faster then 1 would be when inserting/updating a row (with the condition the work is done only on table 1). When selecting I see no reason for 4 to be faster then 1. Not even if you select data that would normally be in 1. (unless you do something like select * from table)

Comment: If for instance you have BLOBs in your table the query will be slower even if the BLOB itself isn't part of the queried columns. Another reason can be the mapping of class inheritance. See my comment to Diego's post.

Comment: 1. We are talking about generics, and not specifics. I am interested in SQL to application not application to SQL. If an ORM is designing your DB that is a totally other thing. So you would not put yourself the question on how to do it cause you have nothing to say in it.
2. We are not talking of wide tables. Wide tables use column sets, which are untyped XMLs so they add in theirself an entirely new set of complexity.